# How can I use vpn to remote into my windows gateway again?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, troubleshooting, windows-server-2012-r2

I was working on our windows server, changed the local time, then restarted windows, after doing that I can no longer reach it from my vpn(can't even ping it). I can still access it on local network and it has the same ip but vpn needs to be working again. Any ideas what my issue might be? Thanks.

Comment: The probable reason is that you set the time incorrectly, and caused certificates to become invalid.  Since you can reach it on the network, set the date & time correctly again, so the certs will again be valid.  Wouldn't hurt to restart the server remotely too.

Comment: I've tried that already, must be something else or a little more than that, thanks for the response though